# Angular Flex Layout: Responsive layout combining row and column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

Im learning [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout), and I'm trying to create a responsive UI. 
I have years of experience with bootstrap grid system, but I can't seem to understand how to accomplish the following ([live demo](http://akveo.com/ngx-admin/#/pages/dashboard?utm_source=github&utm_medium=ngx_admin_readme&utm_campaign=demo)):

On large monitors: 
[image]

On medium monitors: 
[image]

On mobile:

[image]

If I understand it correctly, I have to use a combination of `rows` and `columns`, like the below code

```
    <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutGap="0.5%" fxLayoutAlign="center">
      <div fxFlex="25%"> ..code left out..</div>
      <div fxFlex="25%"> ..code left out..</div>
      <div fxFlex="25%"> ..code left out..</div>
      <div fxFlex="25%"> ..code left out..</div>
   </div>
```

On small screen, the layout changes from `row` to `column`, meaning I have implemented the UI examples above for large and mobile monitors.

**Question:** How can I implement the UI for medium monitors (see above picture)? I cant understand how to combine `row` and `column`

Answer (score 9):

I would minimize your code by looping over the array of items. And I changed the transition from md to sm instead of going to straight to xs, but its your preference. I am subtracting layout gap as well (-0.5%).

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutGap="0.5%" fxLayoutAlign="center">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <li
      fxFlex="0 1 calc(25% - 0.5%)"
      fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 0.5%)"
      fxFlex.lt-sm="100%">
   </li>
</ng-container>
   </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. How can I just give padding the sub elements using the same structure? like margin-bottom: 5px ?

Comment: Seems like `fxLayoutWrap` is no longer available. Use `fxLayout="row wrap"` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can try that way:

```css
    .container { // for desktop & tablet
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    
    .container div {
        width: 25%
    }
    
    @media for middle { // for tablet (mid)
        .container div {
            width: 50%
        }
    }
    
    @media for mobile { //for mobile
        .container {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
    
        .container div {
            width: 100%
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help, sorry for not so detail, but it's just a fast tip with flex.

Thanks